# cron running php file which uses shell_exec and redis-cli

Tags: php, bash, cron, redis

I have a cronjob that runs the following:

`* * * * * php /path/to/phpfile.php >> /cronlog.txt`

when I run the php file in bash everything works, but when the cronjob runs it, one command fails:

`shell_exec("redis-cli ping");` and returns an error that `sh: 1: redis-cli: not found`

Does anyone know why the cron user using PHP `shell_exec` would not be able to use the `redis-cli` command?

**update**
`git diff /env_term.txt /env_cron.txt`

```
-SHELL=/bin/bash
-TERM=screen
-SSH_CLIENT=*************
-SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/0
-USER=root
-LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.
-TERMCAP= { a bunch of giberish }
-PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
-MAIL=/var/mail/root
-STY=*************
-PWD=*************
-LANG=en_US.UTF-8
-HOME=/root
-SHLVL=2
 LANGUAGE=en_US:en
+HOME=/root
 LOGNAME=root
-WINDOW=2
-SSH_CONNECTION=*************
-LESSOPEN=| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s
-LESSCLOSE=/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s
-_=/usr/bin/env
+PATH=/usr/bin:/bin
+LANG=en_US.UTF-8
+SHELL=/bin/sh
+PWD=*************
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you check if your PATH variable is the same when cron is called.
A quick check is to add a dummy cron job to output the current environment variables passed to cron:

```
* * * * * env > /tmp/env.out
```

And then compare this output with when you run the env command from the terminal

Comment: Thanks! I ran a git diff on the two outputs and have added it to my question.

Comment: Well PATH env vars are different.  What output does `which redis_cli` give you

Comment: `which redis-cli` = `/usr/local/bin/redis-cli`

Comment: Ok so you need to add /usr/local/bin to the PATH variable. There are numerous ways of doing this. You can do this in your php script, the profile of the user account for which cron is running, or adding it to the top of your crontab.

Answer (score 0):

try this solution:

```
cat cronjob
* * * * * php /path/to/phpfile.php >> /path/to/cronlog.txt
```

Then:

```
chmod +x cronjob    
/etc/init.d/crond start  #redhat based servers like centos
/etc/init.d/cron  start  #debian based servers like ubuntu

crontab cronjob
```

Comment: `chmod: cannot access 'cronjob': No such file or directory` and 
`cronjob: No such file or directory`

Comment: you should open a file with text editor name it `cronjob`, then write `* * * * * php /path/to/phpfile.php >> /path/to/cronlog.txt`

Answer (score 0):

You can give absolute path of redis-cli to avoid any such issue related to environment variable.